# What is the set $\mathbb{R}^{\nvDash}$ defined as?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

The set $\mathbb{R}^{\nvDash}$ is used in my multivariable-calculus assignment, but I do not know what the superscript '$\nvDash$'  means on the set of real numbers. The context in which it used is that a curve lies in set domain and I must evaluate its line integral.

Thanks!

-Bryan

Comment: Perhaps a typo.  I've never seen $\nvDash$ used in multivariable calculus.

Comment: This is a nonstandard notation. We are not the correct people to ask. You should refer to your book/refer to your lecture notes/ask your teacher or classmates.

Comment: I think the symbol $⊭$ appears as a superscript by default when you make some mistake in your Latex. I don't recall which one but I am sure I have done that twice.

Comment: @nombre It is what happens whenever I blackboard bold the number $2$ in my editor (using MikTeX). Maybe the author meant something like $\mathbb{R}^2$. But don't guess from what I'm saying OP, go ask your teacher.

Comment: @nombre that's a brilliant catch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this is in all likelihood the result of a typo: 
`\mathbb{R^2}` (instead of `\mathbb{R}^2`) can produce what you see. Other exponents like 1, 3, 4  would produce similar but distinct things.

Comment: Ah, I see now. $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ certainly makes much more sense in the question provided. Thanks for all of the comments, particularly @nombre and @neuguy!